# Move to day view when click on month view cell

Tags: react-big-calendar

Want to change the view programatically from month to day using state when month cell is clicked, the click event is getting captured, but isn't working:

```jsx
const localizer = BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment);

export default class Calendario extends React.Component {
  state = {
    defaultView: "month",
    defaultDate: new Date()
  };

  renderCell = props => (
    <Card
      {...props.children.props}
      onClick={() => {
        this.handleSelect(props.value);
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Card>
  );

  handleSelect = (date) => {
    this.setState({ defaultView: "day" });
  };
  render() {
    const { defaultView, defaultDate } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Agenda</h4>
        <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "600px" }}>
          <BigCalendar
            components={{
              dateCellWrapper: this.renderCell
            }}
            defaultDate={defaultDate}
            defaultView={defaultView}
            localizer={localizer}
            startAccessor="start"
            endAccessor="end"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I've looking the API docs, the most similar is onView, but it's triggered from within the library.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Toolbar in which you will have access to `onView`

```js
export const CustomToolbar = ({ onView, views = ['month', 'week', 'day', 'agenda'] }) => (
  <div>
    {
      views.map(view => (
        <button
          key={view}
          onClick={() => onView(view)}
        >
          {view}
        </button>
      ))
    }
  </div>
)

<BigCalendar components={{ toolbar: CustomToolbar }} />
```